# Visible ToolTipText at different positions simultenously?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I set a ToolTipText for different positions, which will appear whenever I place the mouse on that location.

Now, I'd like all the ToolTipTexts which are setted for those particular positions to occur at the same time once I move the mouse into the panel.

Is this even possible with ToolTipText or is there any other alternative to do this?

Comment: It's not possible using the existing tooltip api. You could write your own using JWindows a Stack of some kind and a Timer...

Answer (score 0):

ToolTipText is not the right way to do this.

Instead we go through the set of positions, we want to have a text popping out and call this function:

g.drawString("TheText", position_XCoordinate, position_YCoordinate);

This is the result. The red numbers are created by the method. Of course, the number is painted over the green rectangles but for me this was okay as far as the numbers can be seen.

[image]

Comment: And paint on what? What about when the popup needs to display beyond the bounds of current window?

Comment: It would be painted on the panel itself with the given location. Is there a way to do it beyond the bounds of the panel/window itself?

Comment: If you're painting directly to the panel, are you overriding `paintComponent` or `paint`?  Do you have other components within this panel?  When painting to components, you can paint beyond there visible bounds, but it won't paint anything, you'd need an external window to do it...

Comment: The method g.drawString(...) is being called in the paintComponent-method. Since the class extends JPanel it overrides the paintCompnent of JPanel.

Comment: So you're using it as something like the glass pane? Otherwise you could end up with components painting over what you've painted...

Comment: No, I did not use a glass pane. I never heard of it. You are right; it did actually paint over what I had painted before. But in my scenario this was okay since it was only one number indicating a property of a node. I try to edit a picture to my answer, so the result can be viewed by others.

Comment: The issue I would have, is `paintComponent` is called after the other components have been painted, meaning that the text would painted under other components AND it might not even be called when child components are painted, again, painting over it...